# React Native splash screen and soft navigation keys

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I've added Splash Screen using https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen in my RN app and got next problem: if android device has soft navigation keys, the splash screen changes it's height after a few ms on the screen. Seems like the initial height is the screen height and the next one is window height (screen height without soft navigation keys bar).

Is there any way to fix it and set the splash screen height constantly?

`launch_screen.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/welcome_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

`splash_screen_native.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/welcome_background"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```